# How to group data into time buckets of a specified interval using Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm trying to write a query, where the data for a certain time range is grouped in groups of x days from the start of the date range.

An example would be:

daterange : `05/11/2023 to 05/12/2023`

So my expected result would be the following if I was trying to group by 3 days:

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 05/11/2023 | 1 |
| 08/11/2023 | 16 |
| 11/11/2023 | 2 |
| 14/11/2023 | 33 |
| 17/11/2023 | 4 |
| 20/11/2023 | 5 |
| 23/11/2023 | 6 |
| 26/11/2023 | 1 |
| 29/11/2023 | 1 |
| 02/12/2023 | 4 |

Initially i was tying to accomplish it with `toStartOfInterval` method, but later realized that the intervals produced by this method are relative to `1970-01-01` Hence the grouping are not guaranteed to be within the specified date range.

Comment: Did you try grouping by toStartOfDay()?

Comment: yes, I tried grouping using `toStartOfDay()` , but this method will group all chats which happen in a day to that particular date.

In my case I want to group data of 3 days, or 4 days together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH 
  toDate ('2023-11-05') as d_start
, toDate ('2023-11-10') as d_end
, intDiv (dt - d_start, 3) as grp
SELECT 
  d_start + 3 * grp as d
, count () as cnt
FROM VALUES 
(
  'dt Date'
, (toDate ('2023-11-05'))
, (toDate ('2023-11-06'))
, (toDate ('2023-11-07'))

, (toDate ('2023-11-08'))
, (toDate ('2023-11-08'))
, (toDate ('2023-11-09'))
, (toDate ('2023-11-10'))

, (toDate ('2023-11-11'))
)
WHERE dt BETWEEN d_start AND d_end
GROUP BY grp


|d         |cnt|
|----------|---|
|2023-11-05|3  |
|2023-11-08|4  |
```

Comment: Im not sure if this was the most efficient way of solving the problem, but I also implemented something very similar to what you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test (a UInt64, b Date) Engine = Log;

CREATE FUNCTION relativeDateTrunc AS (date, relative, days) ->  relative + INTERVAL ((date - relative) / days)::UInt32 * days DAYS;

INSERT INTO test SELECT
    number,
    CAST(now(), 'Date') - (rand() % 30)
FROM numbers(18);

WITH (
        SELECT min(b)
        FROM test
    ) AS min
SELECT
    b,
    relativeDateTrunc(b, min, 3) AS relative_to_date,
    CAST(toStartOfInterval(b, toIntervalDay(3)), 'Date') AS relative_to_epoch
FROM test
ORDER BY b ASC

Query id: ef663953-5c5e-4dac-af75-132e2f909791

┌──────────b─┬─relative_to_date─┬─relative_to_epoch─┐
│ 2023-11-11 │       2023-11-11 │        2023-11-10 │
│ 2023-11-13 │       2023-11-11 │        2023-11-13 │
│ 2023-11-13 │       2023-11-11 │        2023-11-13 │
│ 2023-11-14 │       2023-11-14 │        2023-11-13 │
│ 2023-11-17 │       2023-11-17 │        2023-11-16 │
│ 2023-11-18 │       2023-11-17 │        2023-11-16 │
│ 2023-11-20 │       2023-11-20 │        2023-11-19 │
│ 2023-11-20 │       2023-11-20 │        2023-11-19 │
│ 2023-11-23 │       2023-11-23 │        2023-11-22 │
│ 2023-11-24 │       2023-11-23 │        2023-11-22 │
│ 2023-11-28 │       2023-11-26 │        2023-11-28 │
│ 2023-11-29 │       2023-11-29 │        2023-11-28 │
│ 2023-12-01 │       2023-11-29 │        2023-12-01 │
│ 2023-12-01 │       2023-11-29 │        2023-12-01 │
│ 2023-12-01 │       2023-11-29 │        2023-12-01 │
│ 2023-12-04 │       2023-12-02 │        2023-12-04 │
│ 2023-12-05 │       2023-12-05 │        2023-12-04 │
│ 2023-12-08 │       2023-12-08 │        2023-12-07 │
└────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘

18 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.006 sec.
```